# Comment vote coloring is backwards

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, meta

> [image: screenshot]

High voted comments are in black text and look boring and unremarkable, while comments with a few votes have the red "hot" color on them. (I have no idea what is with the blue 25 :P)

Could this be changed so that highly voted comments actually look highly voted?

Comment: Maybe the the font size should = the number of votes?

Comment: @Yuck No. Never.

Comment: IDK, I mean if a comment gets 200 votes I think it deserves a 200 point font. Comic Sans for anything 100+ as well.

Comment: Somehow the white in this new Meta looks "whiter" than before and it hurts my eyes.

Comment: *proudly claims first (new) MSE good question badge* :-P

Comment: This is funny. :P

Comment: With Troyen's answer as addendum, seems like SE uses a single color palette per-site both for comment score and "x characters left".

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I'm even more interested on how replying to "@yuck" adds a built-in sense of disdain for their last point out of the gate (fitting in this case, but presumably not always).

Comment: @Jaydles Is this something you guys are still thinking about? I've been using the design for six months and I still find the colors confusing, especially the use of red for non-errors and gray for errors like too many characters.

Comment: @troyen, (and doorknob) not sure where this landed, but I'll poke the design team. It feels off to me, too, but want to be specific: Am I right that good fix would probably go from grey=>muted color=>brighter or richer shade of same color, yes?  It seems like the things that feel weird on this site is that red & blue aren't on the same spectrum, plus the black feels like a reversal of the "add color for more votes" momentum, yes?

Comment: @Jaydles That's correct.  Or at the least, if you're going to use red, put red at the top end.

Comment: @Jaydles looks like your poke did not have any effect. Or more likely, Jin did not get enough bacon.

Comment: @Troyen And [tag:status-completed] is red too.

Answer (score 33):

This also affects the "X characters left" color when writing comments.

From 600-360 characters remaining, the text is gray:

> [image: Gray text at 360 characters remaining]

From 359-240 characters remaining, the text turns red:

> [image: Red text at 359 characters remaining]

From 239-120 characters remaining, the text turns blue:

> [image: Blue text at 208 characters remaining]

Then, under 120 characters, the text is back to gray:

> [image: Gray text at 0 characters remaining]

Having too many characters is also gray instead of the more common red used on other sites to indicate an error.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be fixed when the design of MSE was updated (March 2, 2015), yay!

> [image]

Comment: This definitely looks better! I'm curious as to the vote threshold at which the comment color changes. It seems to "fade up" from gray to brown to black to red. Would you clarify that for me? Thanks!

Comment: I see you are using Ubuntu.