# The "x characters remaining" indicator on comments shows red for 350 characters remaining, but changes to blue when there are 250 characters remaining

Tags: bug, comments, design

While typing out a rather long comment, I noticed the "x characters remaining" turns read when you get below ~350 characters remaining:

[image]

That's great, but it turns to blue another ~100 characters later:

[image]

What's up with that?

I realize [they say](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56428/why-is-blue-used-as-a-background-color-to-indicate-no-signal) blue can mean "caution", but this color arrangement doesn't make sense, especially since the overall theme of MSE is blue.

Comment: Maybe you mean "turns to blue [for the first time]", or "reverts / turns back to grey" beyond the lowest threshold? The behavior (and color choice!) does seem odd, but blue is at least unambiguously associated with numbers between the last two thresholds. Grey is the more ambiguous color.

Comment: @NickStauner Oh you're right. For some reason I thought it was blue to begin with. Let me fix that.

Comment: Highly related (same problem): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229764/comment-vote-coloring-is-backwards

Comment: @Doorknob Hm, might be considered a duplicate.