# Grace period for bounties look funny in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, ios-app

I'm pretty sure I offered more than +0 on this, and it definitely didn't end (null)

> [image]

Link to question previously in grace period:

[Comment vote coloring is backwards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229764/248072)

A new development: With no winning answer chosen, and grace period expired, the bounty notice is still there. Or is this a local caching issue? Either way it's a bug; the screenshot was definitely taken within the grace period, and was wrong. The fact that it still shows up may be related or may be a second bug

Comment: So, you're saying you saw this state "bounty ends (null)" even before the bounty ended?

Comment: No, it only broke in grace period, then stayed there for another week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237722/closed-as-null-by-null)

> Indeed, a bug existed where this bottom bar with closed/on hold/bounty
>   messaging would not get removed when the state of the question has
>   changed.
>
> This should be fixed in the next Appstore update.

This should already be fixed in the latest Beta version of the app 1.1.0.124.