# Closed as (null) by (null)

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, ios-app, reopen-closed

In the iOS app, questions that have been reopened still show as closed. Clicking the footer shows:

[image: Closed as (null) by (null)]

Comment: was the question reopened while you were looking at it?  Or was it previously reopened before you clicked on it?

Comment: @psubsee2003 No it was reopened several hours ago. I tried refreshing the question just to be sure. [Here's the question from my example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182452/javascript-regex-validation-for-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, a bug existed where this bottom bar with closed/on hold/bounty messaging would **not get removed** when the state of the question has changed.

This should be fixed in the next Appstore update.

Comment: (null) job! :-)